# Binding repeated divs with a bit different contents in the divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on repeated divs that there are some changes within them. Let say I have some buttons on my page that open a modal dialog when being clicked. However, the content within the modal is a bit different for each button. I mean 80% of what inside the modal is repeatedly used across those button and the remaining 20% changes according to each specific button.

I'm tired of duplicating the whole div (modal) and making just small changes to fit each button because I currently have 24 buttons on the page and the number is increasing in the near future.

So, I'm asking if there's an excellent way to cope with this issue. Thank you all.

ps. Sorry if I'm not so clear in explaining the problem. Just a newbie here lol.

Comment: Please provide some code for us to work with. It's very hard to answer an imaginary question.

Comment: Maybe use just one modal and with javascript just change the 20% that's different for each modal.

Comment: javascript or jquery or other library that would make things easier, no code, no chocolate :)

Comment: @4castle Thanks sir. You can take a look at this demo from Shahen Algoo. I adopt his work to my website. https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa

Comment: @Chris Thanks you Chris. I'm thinking of Javascript too but I have no clue with my zero knowledge of js. Could you please guide me a little more?

Comment: Before you ask a question about JavaScript or jQuery, it's probably best that you've gone through at least a basic tutorial first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point all of the buttons to a template modal, and then when a button is clicked, modify the template modal with the dynamic information. You can store the dynamic information in an array of objects, or you could create a system for storing the dynamic information in the HTML, but hidden.

For example:

```js
var contents = [{
    title: "Header 1",
    body: "Body 1"
},{
    title: "Header 2",
    body: "Body 2"
}];

$("button[id^=modal]").click(function() {
    var content = contents[this.id.substring(5) - 1]; // id gives index of content in array
    $("#myModal .modal-title").html(content.title);
    $("#myModal .modal-body").html(content.body);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button id="modal1" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal 1</button>

<button id="modal2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal 2</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><!--Template Title--></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><!--Template Body--></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5s9kw5z/1/)

Comment: Hooray! That's all I want! Thank you a lot for helping me after hours of searching. Still get confused about javascript but I'll study it myself anyway :)

Comment: Yay! I'm happy to help answer any of your questions about it once you've studied it some.